# NodeJs - Rendering same page after multiple SELECT queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, nunjucks

I have below codes in my index.js file. I can print data of profile table. And i need to print data of resume table also in same (index.njk) page. But i couldn't. I also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128323/rendering-view-after-multiple-select-queries-in-express) but i am new and couldn't modify those codes according to my project. Can you please help?

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
router = express.Router(),
app = express();
var pg =require('pg');

// DB Connect string
var connect = {
user: 'arslan', 
database: 'resumedb', 
password: '1984',
host: 'localhost', 
port: 5432, 
max: 10, 
idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, 
};

router.get('/', function(req, res){
pg.connect(connect, function(err, client, done, skills){
  if(err){
    return console.error('errrr', err)
  }
  //Get Profile Informations
client.query('select id,fname,lname,title,description,profileimage from profile', function(err, result){

    if(err){
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
   if(result.rows.length > 0) {
          res.render('index.njk', { 
                profileName: result.rows[0].fname,
                profileLName: result.rows[0].lname , profileTitle: result.rows[0].title
              , profileDesc: result.rows[0].description 
              , profileImage: result.rows[0].profileimage
          });

       console.log(result.rows[0].profileimage);
    }else {
        console.log('No rows found in DB');
    }
    done() 
});
}); 
});
```

Comment: Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it is the easiest way to structure both dependent and independent queries ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for all async stuff is using Promises.
Your code uses the config for a connection pool, but later you dont use a pool, but its often a good idea to use one.
You create a new module `db.js` to query the db

```
const pg = require('pg')

const connect = { // Normaly you would use an config file to store this information
  user: 'arslan',
  database: 'resumedb',
  password: '1984',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  max: 10,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
}

let pool = new pg.Pool(config)

exports.query = (query, values) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if (err)
        return reject(err)
      client.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
        done()
        if (err)
          return reject(err)
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  })
}

exports.queryOne = (query, values) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.query(query, values).then(rows => {
      if (rows.length === 1) {
        resolve(rows[0])
      } else if (rows.length === 0) {
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject(new Error('More than one row in queryOne'))
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}

pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
  console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack)
})
```

and then in your route

```
// ...
const db = require('./db')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  let profileQuery = db.queryOne('select id,fname,lname,title,description,profileimage from profile')
  let resumeQuery = db.query('???')
  Promise.all([profileQuery, resumeQuery]).then(([profile, resume]) => {
    if (!profile) {
        return res.status(404).send('Profile not found') // error page
    res.render('index.njk', { 
            profileName: profile.fname,
            profileLName: profile.lname,
            profileTitle: profile.title,
            profileDesc: profile.description,
            profileImage: profile.profileimage
      })
  }).catch(err => {
    next(err)
  })

})
```

If you want to make a single query you can use `db.query('select 1 + 1').then(rows => { /* your code */}).catch(err => { next(err) })`.
Because you often only want one row you can use `queryOne`. It is returning `undefined` with no rows, the row you want, or an error for multiple rows

The `next()` with an error as argument will call the express error handlers. There you can log the error and return 500. You should create your own for that

Please ask if you dont understand something, because it could be complicated for the first time :)

Comment: Your code is really complicate :) I will need much time for work on it and tick if works. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Hi @Julian, i couldn't use this code. I used logic with answer of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128323/rendering-view-after-multiple-select-queries-in-express). I share my code in answer. They are working fine but i need to find a better way connect to PostgreSql. Because  my web page is stuck after after 2nd click. Can you please review my code help me about connect?

Comment: Why couldnt you use it? In your code the querys are executed one after another and not at the same time, but thats ok if you dont need faster response times. What is the error for the second call (use `if (err) { console.log(err) }` or better an error handler and `next` like i described in my answer). It could be that your mistake is in using a mix of code for a single connection and a connection pool. take a look at the example here https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres for a single connection you use client.end instead of done

Comment: i am new because of that it is getting time to understand :) . I will work on your code during optimization later again after all page completed. But now, by using Pool like in [link](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) page, it is working fine now. And i will continue to finish project by this logic. Thanks so much for your help.